# How to get translated word from google translator in java?

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

I am using the following codes to get the translated word from the google translator in java.

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/"+text).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36").get();
org.jsoup.nodes.Element result = doc.getElementById("result_box");
translatedword=result.text();
```

But I am getting empty string. why?

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup might not be the best tool for this.  [Google has an API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) for their language translation that might be better for you.